# not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: google-chrome-extension

If I run this Code:

```
function sendRequest() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "http://www.google.com/search?XXXX", true);
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
          alert( req.responseText );
        }
      }
    };
  req.send();
}
```

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/search?XXXX. Origin chrome-extension://loifkhcbcjakjhcmecadcbdgfldfjfce is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

why??
In manifest file I have:

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

Demi

Comment: Are you running this code in a Content script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work for a packaged Chrome app, but not a hosted one.